# get all the sub parent folders from given path in java

Tags: java, url, path

I am trying to print all parent folders from the path specified using Java.

For instance,I got this path

```
/root/p0/p1/p2/p3/report
```

Now my expected output is

```
/root/p0/p1/p2/p3

/root/p0/p1/p2

/root/p0/p1

/root/p0

/root
```

How can we do this in Java? Any pre-defined functions exist in Java or by looping it? How to loop this path and get the expected parent url's?

Comment: split the string on `/` and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `getParent` form `Path`, or `gerParentFile` from `File`. Your code can look like:

```
public static void printParents(File f){
    while(f != null){
        f = f.getParentFile();
        if (f !=null && !f.getName().isEmpty()) 
            System.out.println(f);
    }
}
public static void printParents(String f){
    printParents(new File(f));
}
```

---

You can also use String methods like `split` to get all parts from this path. Then you can join parts you want like

```
public static void printParents(String path){
    String[] elements = path.split("(?<!^)/");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(elements[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<elements.length; i++){
        System.out.println(sb);
        sb.append("/").append(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am calling a method with a string parameter like getParentPaths(String url)

Comment: @Faizahamed added method which uses String argument

Comment: wat is this Path? i am getting problem in compiling a class.

Comment: can we go bit logical like spiting and looping it and all.. instead of doing this?

Comment: @Faizahamed `Path` and `Paths` are classes added in Java 7. They ware part of new API placed in `java.nio.file` package, which is meant to replace old `File` class. Are you perhaps using Java 6 or earlier?

Comment: Then simply use `File` instead. I will update my answer. Also in age of Java 8  you should mention that you are using Java 6.

Comment: i get this output...\root\daviewviews\p1\p2\p3
\root\daviewviews\p1\p2
\root\daviewviews\p1
\root\daviewviews
\root
\
null..........its even printng "/" and "null" at the end.

Comment: @Faizahamed I updated my answer to use `File` and eliminate `/` and `null` from output.

Comment: Here is link to revision https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32081030/3. But you should also see it if you refresh current page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the getParent function:

```
public static String getParentName(File file) {
if(file == null || file.isDirectory()) {
        return null;
}
String parent = file.getParent();
parent = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, parent.length());
return parent;      
}
```